# Google Analytics API, getting constantly error 500 , when ask for profiles list

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I have an script to update the profile list using

```
//all this code is inside a Class, and in the class constructor, always update the token 
$this->token = $this->getToken($this->accountId);
$tokenData = json_decode($this->token);

if($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
     $this->client->refreshToken($tokenData->refresh_token);
     $this->token = $this->client->getAccessToken();

     $this->accessToken = json_decode($this->token)->access_token;
     $this->saveToken($this->token,$this->accountId);
}

....

$this->service = new Google_Service_Analytics($this->client);


..
// then  i ask for the profiles
$profiles = $this->service->management_profiles->listManagementProfiles("~all", "~all",array('max-results' => 500));
```

but when i run this code i almost always get this error

```
Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles?max-results=500&key=##ACESS_KEY## : (500) Backend Error
```

this code, sometimes work, sometimes not , i have to be very lucky to just work , and i know is not a token problem because i can run other request like getting the visits for an specific profile without problem , i reduced the max-results to 200,100,50... etc, still happening  , i also have been update to the lastest code from google api , any clue?

Comment: 500 error is normally just a random server hiccup have you tried resubmitting the request?

Comment: i do, if i try several time it work eventually,

Comment: Its what I do.  I never did get any official word back from Google.  we (my boss and I) decided it was probably something on the server acting up and just kicking out that 500 error.  I have seen it for a while.  Btw depending upon what you are doing this is faster https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAccountSummariesGuide

Comment: oh, i will try with AccountSummary and let you know, thanks :D